# Making link keep the CSS hover effect when being on that section link

Tags: css, hover

I'm working on a website that contains sections, each of which has a hover effect. I want to keep the hover effect active after clicking on the section you want.

Can someone tell me how to achieve this?

CSS:

```
.btncstm:hover {
   background: #C01527;
   text-decoration: none;
   color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="[section1_link]" class="btncstm">Section1</a>
<a href="[section2_link]" class="btncstm">Section2</a>
<a href="[sectionN_link]" class="btncstm">SectionN</a>
```

Comment: This is a fairly broad question, and your lack of code provided makes it difficult to give a specific answer to it. Generally though, a technique I've frequently seen is to use JavaScript to apply an `.active` class to the currently open section, and use that class to attach styling to it.

Comment: @Serlite new here, didn't think about it, either way, this is what the CSS looks like:

'.btncstm:hover {
  background: #C01527;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#FFFFFF;
}'

For the hover effect, and the html:

'<a href="[section1_link]" class="btncstm">Section1</a>
<a href="[section2_link]" class="btncstm">Section2</a>
<a href="[sectionN_link]" class="btncstm">SectionN</a>'

Comment: @Serlite new here, didn't think about it, either way, this is what the CSS looks like:

`.btncstm:hover {
  background: #C01527;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#FFFFFF;
}`

For the hover effect, and the html:

`<a href="[section1_link]" class="btncstm">Section1</a>
<a href="[section2_link]" class="btncstm">Section2</a>
<a href="[sectionN_link]" class="btncstm">SectionN</a>`

Sorry for the repost, didnt know about the different tags and Enter :/

Comment: Hmm, actually, JavaScript may not be the answer here - when you say sections, do you mean different webpages, or sections on the same webpage (eg. Tabbed content)?

Comment: Yeah, different webpages with different pictures/videos per section, so I want the client to know which section he's at with the hover effect remaining in the link button.

Comment: Another solution is to use PHP, but I assume your website is pure HTML/CSS? I added a simple PHP solution in my answer below, in case you want to look into that option.

Comment: It is actually .php just for the header/footer.inc confort, I was actually testing it out, the other option didn't work thought.

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
.btncstm:visited { background: #C01527; text-decoration: none; color:#FFFFFF; }
```

immediately after your

```
.btncstm:hover { background: #C01527; text-decoration: none; color:#FFFFFF; }
```

or alternatively, you could use the following:

```
.btncstm:hover, .btncstm:visited { background: #C01527; text-decoration: none; color:#FFFFFF; }
```

Comment: What I want is for the links just to appear with the hover effect when you are actually in that section.

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean by 'section'. The only HTML you've given me to work with is the anchor tags.

Comment: Yeah, I mean not actual <section> but different webpages with content tags, for example, some common videos or images, thats why I mentioned sections.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you're looking for can be achieved using JavaScript - unfortunately, CSS alone isn't enough to do it. This particular solution makes use of jQuery.

Create a class `.active` with your hover styles:

```css
.btncstm.active {
   background: #C01527;
   text-decoration: none;
   color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

And use JavaScript (with jQuery in this case) to find the appropriate navigation link and attach the `.active` class to it:

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
    // Get page URL by breaking down window.location
    var page = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

    // Search through each link, compare href to current page
    $("a.btncstm").each( function(){
        if( $(this).attr("href") == page || $(this).attr("href") == "" )
        $(this).addClass("active");
    })
});
```

Here's a [link to the page](http://andornagy.com/active-class-navigation-menu/) from which I adapted the solution - you may find it helpful since it discusses the components in a bit more detail. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

---- *EDIT* ----

If the links are to separate pages, and not sections on one single page, PHP is another way to create a menu that "knows" what page you're on. There are many possible ways to achieve this, but here's an example that adds an `.active` class to the menu item if the current URL matches the link (this usually requires your files to have a .php ending):

```
<a href="[section1_link]" class="btncstm<?php echo ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/section1.php' ? ' active' : '');?>">Section1</a>
<a href="[section2_link]" class="btncstm<?php echo ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/section2.php' ? ' active' : '');?>">Section2</a>
<a href="[sectionN_link]" class="btncstm<?php echo ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/sectionN.php' ? ' active' : '');?>">SectionN</a>
```

---- *END EDIT* ----

Add some jQuery magic to achieve this:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="btncstm">Section1</a> 
<a href="#" class="btncstm">Section2</a> 
<a href="#" class="btncstm">SectionN</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.btncstm:hover, .active {
   background: #C01527;
   text-decoration: none;
   color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.btncstm').on('click', function () {
    $('.btncstm').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/YdGu7/

Comment: I think (based on the comments) the question refers to sections split into separate webpages. Though I agree that the wording was ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, going to research a bit more in that other website @Serlite linked